# HTML Table renders different row heights

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to create an HTML table. I want each row and col to have the same width and height.

For some reason, when inspecting the cells, I notice that there's difference in the heights.

[image]

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why this happens and how it can be fixed?
Note: Should also work on IE11

```css
table{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  color: gray;
  border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      
    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
      
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
table{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  color: gray;
  border: solid 1px;
}
td div {
  height: 50px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
       <div>
          test0
          <br/>
          test0
          <br/>
         
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
       <div>
          test1
          <br/>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
       <div>
          test2
          <br/>
          test2
          <br/>
          test2
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
          test3
          <br/>
          test3
          <br/>
          test3
          <br/>
          test3
          <br/>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I ran your snippet in codepen. there's still height difference in the cells

Comment: Well, the height of the rows changes with the size of the window, but everyone changes equally.

Comment: I agree that the height changes with the size of the window, but it should change and keep the cell heights even. Instead, some cells have around 1 pixel more then others

Comment: This goes back to browser rendering (:

Answer (score 0):

hope this will solve the problem

```
table{
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

td{
    width: 50%;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: It made it worse

Answer (score 0):

Provided fix height to td tag.. hope this will fix your problem.

```
td {
     color: gray;
     border: solid 1px;
     height:121px;
   }
```